# Upload mp3, doc, ppt, sql, zip, tar, rar files

Tags: php

I want to give my users the freedom to upload all types of files in my online storage site. I only know how to upload image files such as these:

```
//other code   
 $_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg"
 $_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg"
 $_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"
 $_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png"
 $_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"
//other code
```

using the ebove code I can upload the given extention files to my site. But I want to upload .mp3 .doc .ppt .docx . pptx .sql and many more possible files. To do that, what should I put in the "question mark" below:

```
 $_FILES["file"]["type"] == ?          // for mp3
 $_FILES["file"]["type"] == ?          // for doc/docx
 $_FILES["file"]["type"] == ?          // for ppt/pptx 
 $_FILES["file"]["type"] == ?          // for sql
 $_FILES["file"]["type"] == ?          // for zip/tar/rar
```

please , tell me if there is any list of all extensions of file and what should I write to upload the asked files?

---Thanks.

Comment: Side note: You should NOT use these mine type "protection" it's very easy bypassed so an attacker can upload an PHP file.. because the browser (HTTP protocol) tells (read hints) the server what kind off file the user is uploading

Comment: To add to what @RaymondNijland said. You could also potentially look at using `SplFileInfo` if you want to get more definitive information around file types.

Comment: Oh and to help with the original question, I would suggest Googling MIME types for those file types.  This is easily available information.

Comment: Information requested in question is easily available via internet search. It adds little value to have that information repeated in a non-authoritative site like SO.

Comment: never looked into the C/C++ source code off PHP behind `SplFileInfo`object so i dont know how save this is... but the safest option would be to parse the files on binary level.. Mp3 file format -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#File_structure (the MIME type off MP3 is also there)  or parse the file on asii for example the sql file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MIME Type provided in `$_FILE['file']['type']` is a information given by the client side and can be falsified. Don't trust it. It can also vary from a machine to another, as you saw yourself there isn't a single MIME description to each extension, so it can be very frustrating to rely on it to take any kind of decision.

Someone can send you a `music.php` and say its a `audio/mp3`, save it in your website folder and you have just given them means to compromise your entire server. Don't do it.

Instead, use the file extension to determine it's type. You can also list all allowed extensions in an array and just check if the file extension exists in this array.

```
$allowed_extensions = array(
    'mp3', 'mp4', 'doc', 'zip', 'rar',
    'docx', 'ppt', 'pps', 'pptx' // ...
);
if (!in_array(pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $allowed_extensions))
    die("You can't upload this.");
```

Or, you can instead prohibit dangerous file extensions and allow everything else, what would be easier to do considering you want to allow "any type of file".

```
$disallowed_extensions = array('exe', 'scr', 'cpl', 'bat', 'php', 'htaccess');
if (in_array(pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $disallowed_extensions))
    die("You can't upload this.");
```

Careful with the file name too. The file name provided in `$_FILES['file']['name']` should be just the file base name, but once again this information is provided by the user and can be including full or relative paths to make your script save it where it shouldn't. Always use `basename($_FILES['file']['name'])` to make sure you are using the file base name when saving the file.

Comment: thanks alot. Thanks for telling me it is possible to send music.php as in audio/mp3 ---I did not know this. Of course it is dangreous! And using basename sounds  secure. Yes I am accepting your answer and your advice. Now for the sake of security I'm going to change my code. :) @Havenard

Answer (score 2):

```
mp3 => ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mp3")
pdf => ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
zip => ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/zip")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/x-zip-compressed")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "multipart/x-zip")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/x-compressed") // one of those depending on the zip file.
sql=> ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/octet-stream")
ppt=> ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint")
pptx=> ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation")

docx=> ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
```

you will need to do some search on those to confirm these are exactly what you are looking for. i am sure it is everywhere.

Comment: thanks, I decided to change my code so I won't be needing this anymore but still it is good to know the way....... :) @Justin